# Как добавить текст через JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть input для того, чтобы пользователь мог писать что-либо. И у меня есть p, чтобы выводить содержимое input в него.

Сейчас я не могу сделать так, чтобы js скопировал текст в input и вставил в p, когда нажимаю на кнопку.

```js
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">HEY</h1>
    <input id="input">
    <p id="comments"></p>
    <script>
    //var comm      = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    for(0 == 1) {
    var    commLabel = document.getElementById('input');
    for(commLabel == null || commLabel == undefined) {
        var    commLabel = document.getElementById('input');
    }; else {
        var comm = 
        commLabel.innerHTML = "";
    };
    };
    //for(comm == undefined || comm == null) {
    //    var comm = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    //}; else {
    //    break;
    //};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change

Comment: мне кажется вы путаете `for` и `if`

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const comments = document.getElementById("comments");

function updateComments() {
  if (input.value && input.value !== '') {
    const comment = document.createElement("div");
    comment.innerHTML = input.value;
    comments.appendChild(comment);
    input.value = "";
  }
}

submit.addEventListener("click", updateComments);
```

Live: https://codesandbox.io/s/j40497lqry

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input oninput="document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML=this.value">
<div id="text"></div>
```